# Upload csv to django models

Tags: django, csv, django-models, django-views

I have django models defined as

```
 class Event(models.Model):
    event_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    OS_CHOICE=(('Win 2003','windows 2003'),
        ('Win 2008','Windows 2008'),
        ('Win XP','Windows XP'),
        ('Win VISTA','Win VISTA'),
        ('Win 2007','Windows 2007'),
        )
    windows=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=OS_CHOICE,default='Win 2003')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return " %s, event_id :%s" \
            % (self.windows, self.event_id)
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'event'
        verbose_name_plural='events'
class Eventgroups(models.Model):
    event=models.ManyToManyField(Event)
    group_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s,  %s" \
            % (self.group_name, self.event)
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'eventgroup'
        verbose_name_plural='eventgroups'
```

I want to write a django view that will anable a user browse to a csv file and click on import to upload/import the selected csv file to the models defined above(consider the M2M field in you answer please).
Will anyone please give some guidance on this?
An example based on my models will be much appreciated.
Regards

Comment: What about that m2m field? How will your csv look like? What kind of data is as rows there, if you think mentioning m2m field is important here?. Thinking of tables - how could you create multi table relations with just single csv sheet?

Comment: Odif i get you.Suppose i didnt have that M2M condition,how could this be achieved?

Comment: If the csv file has column names, which match the field values of event (event_id, OS_CHOICE, windows), then you could use python csv dictreader to create dictionaries from the csv rows and then loop over those rows and just call e = Event(**row), e.save(), where row is one of the csv rows.

Comment: an example on how to use dict reader please in my case Odif

Answer (score 0):

import csv

```
f = 'your/file/name.csv'
with open(f, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.dictreader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        e = Event(**row)
        e.save()
```

I am quite sure you could have taken it all from here too: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html as what i have written here is pretty much copy paste :).